# How to batch extract nth page from pdfs

Tags: pdf

I'd like to extract the 9th page from around ~500 pdfs.
the input name and the output name should be the same.

I have Acrobat installed. Macos 10.13

Acrobat has a nice Action wizard feature - I was able to delete the first 8 pages. After it's more difficult, as the documents are not the same size, they vary from 42 to 58 pages in total.

There's also an execute javascript option, `this.extractPages(8);` but it creates a temporary file with a random name.

**Solutions:**

1/ One way is to use Acrobats *split command* to split the pdf into equally sized chunks. In my example 8 pages. Then I select in Finder only the Part2_ (better to put the identifier in front of file name) files and using the *Acrobat's Action Wizard* delete pages 2-8.
In Acrobat DC to be able to batch split you have to have one pdf open.

2/ Use  [PDFsam](https://pdfsam.org) to extract a specific page

Comment: "The input and output name should be the same" - in different folders, or do you want to replace the original PDF with just page 9?
Are you any good with python? I have a python script that splits PDF pages from received files, so it wouldn't be hard to modify that for just page 9.
https://github.com/benwiggy/PDFsuite/blob/master/Automator_Scripts/splitPDF.py

Comment: I can create duplicates etc so replacing orignals or not is not really a concern.
I'll keep this solution in mind, for the moment I have done what was needed.
It would be great to integrate something like this to Automator